# Merge failures and response from Map Steps in Step Function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

I have a simple Step Function that we can visualize like this:
[image]

Sometimes the Parallel Step throws an exception, but I don't want to finish processing. I want to process all items that have been transferred to Map Parallel Step. Is it possible to process all of them (even there were errors) and return array of all valid executions  and a second one that contains all errors to the Finalize step?

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two ways to handle this:

1. Your Map step can have more than one state in it, so you can add states for handling errors in the "parallel step" state.
2. You can ensure that you catch all exceptions in your handler in "parallel step", then return 2 types of data into your output array that you can post process in a subsequent step